# For loop that allows for variables to overwrite each other

Tags: c++

My question is how do I add onto my for loop so that when it does its multiple iterations, the variables will overwrite each other?

I am trying to take an input text file with three shares like so:

*Google (GOOG)

522.01  2 100

520.66 1.5 80

Apple (AAPL)

389.27 2 150

401.82 1.8 150

Microsoft (MSFT)

25.06 2.5 100

25.07 2 80*

Then later print/write it onto an output text file.

Now when it runs its iteration 3 times, It only displays stock 1 and its correct numbers, but then wrong numbers and no name for the others. So how would I go about making it so the next iterations will overwrite and print another set of answers?

below is the for section code I have:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 3; x++) // for loop to run this part of program 3 times

{

    getline(dataIn, stockName);//Gets the whole first line


    dataIn >> buyingAMT;//These just store whatever is in the line before every space, and sets it with a name 
    dataIn >> buyingComm;//So like it takes the characters leading up to the first space and stores it as buyingAMT.
    dataIn >> numberBought;
    dataIn >> sellingAMT;
    dataIn >> sellingComm;
    dataIn >> numberSold;



    //writing to a file


    buyingComm = buyingComm * buyingAMT;//Mathematical Calculations

    buyingAMT = buyingAMT * numberBought;

    sellingComm = (sellingComm / 100) * numberSold;

    sellingComm = sellingComm * sellingAMT;

    sellingAMT = sellingAMT * numberSold;

    profit = (sellingAMT - sellingComm) - (buyingAMT + buyingComm);

    //Displaying the calculated answers
    fout << setw(20) << left << stockName;

    fout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(15) << right << buyingAMT;

    fout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(15) << right << buyingComm;

    fout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(15) << right << sellingAMT;

    fout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(15) << right << sellingComm;

    fout << setprecision(2) << fixed << setw(15) << right << profit << endl;

    //Storing the results into the overall variables to be used later
    /*totalBuyingAMT += buyingAMT;
    totalBuyingComm += buyingComm;
    totalSellingAMT += sellingAMT;
    totalSellingComm += sellingComm;
    grandProfit += profit;
    */

}
getline(dataIn, junk);//Cleans the remaining unread data

dataIn.close();//closes the input file, so it cant be read any longer

fout.close();

cout << "congrats you are either now screwed or rich!";

return 1;
```

}

[what I get as output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swg1D.jpg)

[what i need to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPUU8.jpg)

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080255/mixing-formatted-input-extractors-with-getline-causes-cout-display-to-stick-toge P.S. please remove the C# tag, they are not the same thing.

Comment: Returning non-zero from `main` indicates failure.

Answer (score 1):

Variables as long as they are not `const` can always be re-written or copied. What it looks like from your code there is an issue with how your extracting the text.

```
dataIn >> buyingAMT;//These just store whatever is in the line before every space, and sets it with a name 
dataIn >> buyingComm;//So like it takes the characters leading up to the first space and stores it as buyingAMT.
dataIn >> numberBought;
dataIn >> sellingAMT;
dataIn >> sellingComm;
dataIn >> numberSold;
```

So what kind of types are `dataIn` and the other variables here? It seems as though your not splitting the text correctly or don't have a way to do that from dataIn.

This is a small example where one line is taken from stdin (although it can be any stream)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  int i;
  std::string input;
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    std::cout << "Please give me some input:";
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << "You gave me:" << input << std::endl;
  }
}

ofstream fout;//data type used to write the data taken from input file and put it on output file
fout.open(output_File_Name);

if (fout.fail())
{
    fout << "Input file not found: " << output_File_Name << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

fout << setw(20) << left;//Setting the labels
fout << "STOCK";

fout << setw(15) << right;
fout << "BUYING AMT";

fout << setw(15) << right;
fout << "BUYING COMM";

fout << setw(15) << right;
fout << "SELLING AMT";

fout << setw(15) << right;
fout << "SELLING COMM";


fout << setw(15) << right;
fout << "PROFIT" << endl;
```

Comment: I have dataIn as ifstream dataIn. Also the other variables are double variables.

Comment: Is each stock name and it's values all on one line, and every stock is in consecutive lines?

Comment: you mean when its being written into a file or read? If you mean written then no the stock name is on its each line going down. each value though in terms of buyingAMT, BuyingComm, etc. are in one line

Comment: Can you copy paste the textfile so we can have a look at it?

Comment: i've added the image of what the text file for output i get, and what I need to get

Comment: So it seems based on your output you aren't properly formatting the result, since your getting numbers like `-555.255.33`. What is `fout`? Whatever your inserting into that file stream is not being newlined or separated by lines.

Comment: my fout is just the variable name of my ofstream. I then added my fout with labels, ive added it to the top